# Gtk3.0 Overlay with Labels on DrawingArea

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gstreamer

I have created a small gtk application that displays an RTP stream in a gtk window. I am also displaying information on top of this video by using the textoverlay element provided by gstreamer. This feels like a back door since it appears to be intended for subtitles.

I would like to display my information using methods provided by gtk. I am currently trying to use the overlay container to hold the drawing area created for the video and then placing a layout container on top of that holding labels.

I am finding that the background of the layout container is being drawn on top of the drawing area, meaning blocked. If I remove the drawing area and use two layout containers with labels in them, overlapping labels are displayed the way that I would expect.

I have tried various combinations of opacity and containers with no luck.

Comment: I don't think placing widgets over a video is a good idea. The best case scenario is that it forces gtk to redraw the widget every time the video renders a frame. The worst case scenario is that it straight up doesn't work, because gstreamer needs exclusive control over the rendering of the video area. If you're going to place something over the video, do it with gstreamer.

Comment: I am open to suggestion seeing as I have found little information regarding this specific issue with overlay. I have seen some suggestions for clutter, and wouldn't be opposed to writing an element for gstreamer at this point.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this as I am looking into the same scenario where I need to display transparent widgets over a drawing area (from libvlc in this case)

Comment: I wound up abandoning GTK for this project. I found a much simpler solution using gstreamer and qt. Version 1.14 of gstreamer provides a qt element called qmlsink which allowed me to create a window displaying video and place objects over the top. It has worked well on my target hardware.